# Adding authorization in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, coreclr

I have noticed there are two different ways the asp.net core application can be globally configured to `Authorize` only authenticated user. I wanted to know what is the difference between these two approaches

1st

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{           
    services.AddAuthorization();
}
```

2nd

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{                  
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AddAuthorization() adds the bits necessary to use the Authorize attribute and policies. It does not apply authorization anywhere, that's left to you. Your description of this globally configuring the app is not correct.

Adding the authorize filter is basically applying the authorize attribute everywhere and requiring authorization over your entire site.

Comment: so do we need to configure both?

Comment: Yes. You need to add, then setup the filter

Comment: You don't have to do both. If you setup a Global Filter, no need for `services.AddAuthorization`.